# How to do multiple instances of Joomla for Template website?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I am thinking of running a website that sells Joomla template (similar like TemplateMonster). When I look at TemplateMonster, what come up into my mind is they have multiple instances of Joomla and they populate the content of every single of them depending on the template.

Is this the only way to achieve this? What if I have 100 templates, do I have to copy paste 100 Joomla?

These are the examples of two different contents:

- http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44048.html
- http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44129.html

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest way would be adding `?template=beez3` to the uri.

More complicated to use extension like [Virtual Domains](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/7557).
Current menu item (and so template) is set based on rules like current URI. Extension is little tricky to setup but could be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I agree, I'm also looking for other alternatives. Because sometimes different template will have different compatible modules to make it looks better.

Comment: Then it's getting complicated :)
Maybe you can set active menu item (`Itemid`) manually manually by system plugin and link modules to it.

Comment: Is it possible to do that? I haven't tried doing something like that before. In your opinion will it be easier if I install another Joomla then?

Comment: I'd look for a such plugin and code one if there isn't one. I'm pretty sure it's possible, it's being done by [Virtual Domains](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/7557) extension which could be what